# Node JS : JSON Refactoring based on the city

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I have the following JSON object:

```
    const data = [
    {
        "city name": "Chennai",
        "product name": "Apple",
        "no of qty": 2,
        "indvidual price": 50,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    },
    {
        "city name": "Chennai",
        "product name": "Samsung",
        "no of qty": 1,
        "indvidual price": 150,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    },
    {
        "city name": "Delhi",
        "product name ": "MIUI",
        "no of qty": 5,
        "indvidual price": 100,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    },
    {
        "city name": "Chennai",
        "product name": "Redmi",
        "indvidual price": 100,
        "no of qty": 1,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    },
    {
        "city name": "Delhi",
        "product name": "Realme",
        "indvidual price": 100,
        "no of qty": 5,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    },
];
```

I'm trying to group, based on the city and the calculate overall qty and cost. The overall cost based on the individual product has different GST we need to calculate and add to the total value.

The excepted JSON is something like this,

```
var result = [
    {
        "city": "chennai",
        "totalqty": 4, //Total qty based on the city
        "totalPrice": 354 //With the GST, Each product have separate gst(59+177+118)
    },
    {
        "city": "Delhi",
        "totalqty": 10, //Total qty based on the city
        "totalPrice": 236 //With the GST, Each product have separate gst(118+118)
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [{
    "city name": "Chennai",
    "product name": "Apple",
    "no of qty": 2,
    "indvidual price": 50,
    "gst tax": 0.18,
  },
  {
    "city name": "Chennai",
    "product name": "Samsung",
    "no of qty": 1,
    "indvidual price": 150,
    "gst tax": 0.18,
  },
  {
    "city name": "Delhi",
    "product name ": "MIUI",
    "no of qty": 5,
    "indvidual price": 100,
    "gst tax": 0.18,
  },
  {
    "city name": "Chennai",
    "product name": "Redmi",
    "indvidual price": 100,
    "no of qty": 1,
    "gst tax": 0.18,
  },
  {
    "city name": "Delhi",
    "product name": "Realme",
    "indvidual price": 100,
    "no of qty": 5,
    "gst tax": 0.18,
  },
];

const dict = {
  city: "city name",
  qty: "no of qty",
  Price: "indvidual price",
  gst: "gst tax",
};

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const cityAlredyExist = acc.find((o) => o.city === curr[dict.city]);
  if (cityAlredyExist) {
    cityAlredyExist.totalqty += curr[dict.qty];
    cityAlredyExist.totalPrice +=
      curr[dict.Price] + curr[dict.Price] * curr[dict.gst];
  } else {
    acc.push({
      city: curr[dict.city],
      totalqty: curr[dict.qty],
      totalPrice: curr[dict.Price] + curr[dict.Price] * curr[dict.gst],
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes bro,its working, But how can we do if the city in json like City name(With space in between) what to do?

Comment: {
        "city name": "Delhi",
        "product name ": "MIUI",
        "no of qty": 5,
        "indvidual price": 100,
        "gst tax": 0.18
    } LIke this

Comment: @Naren Edited answer and see is this what you want?

Comment: Pls look into the question that i have edited. Your edited ans is showing like city is city name, it not a expected result

Answer (score 0):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is useful in this situation. You can then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to pull out a new array that corresponds to your output.

If you have keys with spaces in them in your JSON, simply replace

```
const { gst, price, qty } = rest;
```

with

```
const { 'gst tax': gst, 'individual price': price, qty } = rest;
```

This assigns a label that matches the variables in the rest of the code so you don't need to change anything else.

```js
const data=[{city:"Chennai",product:"Apple",qty:2,price:50,gst:.18},{city:"Chennai",product:"Samsung",qty:1,price:150,gst:.18},{city:"Delhi",product:"MIUI",qty:5,price:100,gst:.18},{city:"Chennai",product:"Redmi",price:100,qty:1,gst:.18},{city:"Delhi",product:"Realme",price:100,qty:5,gst:.18}];

const out = data.reduce((acc, c, i, arr) => {

  // Destructure the city and product, and use `rest`
  // to destructure the rest
  const { city, product, ...rest } = c;
  const { gst, price, qty } = rest;

  // If the city doesn't exist on the object, create it
  // and set some default values
  acc[city] = (acc[city] || { city, product, qty: 0, price: 0 });

  // Update the quantity, and price
  acc[city].qty += qty;
  acc[city].price += gst * price + price;

  // Return the object for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

// And then grab the Object.values
console.log(Object.values(out));
```